# Functions in $L^1$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be a measure space and let $g\colon X\to [-\infty,\infty]$ be a measurable function. Let $p\in[1,\infty)$.

It's true that
$$
\Large\left |g \right |^p\in L^1\implies \left | g \right|\in L^1
$$

For me the answer is yes, as $$\large \int_X \left |g\right | \le \int_X\left |g \right |^p\; d\mu<\infty$$

It's correct?

Comment: This is not true if $X$ has infinite measure. Even if $X$ has finite measure, the inequality as stated can be stated as true if $|g| \geq 1$ , but it's false otherwise : the best inequality requires the LHS to be to the power $p$.

Comment: @NathMath You're welcome, I see you're still editing the post so let me know when it's done. I see the codomain of $g$ changing, so I hope that is fixed. In any case, the inequality on the last line is unfortunately incorrect and needs changing (even in a finite measure space).

Comment: Why is $|g| \leq |g|^{p}$? Is this true when  $g$ is a constant?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy No, because $p\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: A small notational advice: Instead of writing $|g|^{p}\in L^{1}$  you can directly write $g\in L^{p}$

Comment: Say $g(x)=1/2$ and $p=2$. Your inequality now says $1/2<1/4$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $(X,\mathcal{F},\mu)$ is a finite measure space and $0<p<q<\infty$ then $L^{q}\subset L^{p}$ .

$$\int_{X} |f|^{p}\,d\mu = \int_{|f|\le 1} |f|^p\,d\mu + \int_{|f|> 1} |f|^p\,d\mu \\\le \int_{|f|\le 1} 1\,d\mu + \int_{|f|> 1} |f|^q\,d\mu \leq \mu(X) + \int_{X} |f|^q\,d\mu  < \infty$$

The case when $q=\infty$ is easier as $|f|\leq M\,,a.s[\mu]$ for some $M\in(0,\infty)$ .

Hence $\int_{X}|f|^{p}\,d\mu\leq M^{p}\mu(X)<\infty $ .

As stated in the comments and the above answer it fails for infinite measure spaces.

Example $\frac{1}{x}\mathbf{1}_{[1,\infty)}$ is $L^{2}$ but not $L^{1}$. Or a slightly different but related example. Take $(\Bbb{N},2^{\Bbb{N}},\mu)$ where $\mu$ is the counting measure.

Then if $f(n)=\frac{1}{n}$ we have $f\in L^{2}(\mu)$ but not $L^{1}(\mu)$  as $\displaystyle\int_{\Bbb{N}}|f|\,d\mu=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}f(n)$ diverges but $\displaystyle\int_{\Bbb{N}}|f|^{2}\,d\mu=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} (f(n))^{2}\,d\mu=\frac{\pi^{2}}{6}$  .

Answer (score 1):

In the real line, just pick:

$f(x) = \begin{cases} 1/x & x>1 \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$

Then you see that $|f|^2$ is in $L^1$ but $|f|$ is not in $L^1$. As Sarvech is correctly pointing out in the comments, these kind of examples can happen when you domain $X$ has a infinite measure.